# Prevent repeated alert messages when using FLAG_SECURE to block screenshots in Android app

Tags: android, react-native, screenshot

I am using [react-native-pvt-jail-monkey](https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/react-native-pvt-jail-monkey) to block screenshots and recordings in my app. Upon user tap on the secure screen button, app will call to a native module method that sets the FLAG_SECURE flag and secure the screen. However, when user tries to take a screenshot, an alert message appears, but it keeps popping up repeatedly, which is not the intended behavior.

Question: How can I make the alert message to appear just once after user tries to take a screenshot?

Here's the relevant part of the code:

react-native-pvt-jail-monkey

```
public void secureScreen(String label) {
    final ReactContext context = getReactApplicationContext();

    if (context != null && context.getCurrentActivity() != null) {
        context.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                context.getCurrentActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
            }
        });
    }

    ReactContext reactContext = context;
    if (reactContext != null) {
        EventDispatcher eventDispatcher = reactContext.getNativeModule(UIManagerModule.class).getEventDispatcher();
        eventDispatcher.addListener(new EventDispatcherListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEventDispatch(Event event) {
                try {
                    if (event.getEventName().equals("topShow")) {
                        if (context.getCurrentActivity() != null && context.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(event.getViewTag()) instanceof ReactModalHostView) {
                            ReactModalHostView dialog = (ReactModalHostView) context.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(event.getViewTag());
                            dialog.getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
import JailMonkey from 'react-native-pvt-jail-monkey';

<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    JailMonkey.secureScreen("Blocked");
  }}
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    width: 200,
    height: 70,
    borderRadius: 20,
    alignSelf: "center",
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  }}
>
  <Text style={{ color: "white", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Secure screen</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "captureproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-pvt-jail-monkey": "^2.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

Here's the video for better understanding: [Demo Video](https://imgur.com/a/ALdXF7l)

Note: Might need to take a closer look to see the flickering of the alert message that shows how it pops up repeatedly

I have tried to use the code from [react-native-screenshot-prevent](https://github.com/killserver/react-native-screenshot-prevent/blob/main/android/src/main/java/com/killserver/screenshotprev/RNScreenshotPreventModule.java) , but it's the same result.

```
@ReactMethod
  public void enableSecureView() {
    if (this.reactContext.hasCurrentActivity()) {
      final Activity activity = this.reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
      if (activity != null) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            reactContext.getCurrentActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```